# Can Wien's displacement law be used to calculate temperature of bodies far away?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Light gets red shifted as it travels large distance then how accurate measurements for temperature can be made?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we know how much the light has been redshifted, due to the fact that spectral features like hydrogen lines are almost always discernible. Because of this, we can account for the redshift and use Wien's law.

There is another type of reddening that occurs when light is scattered by dust on its way. However, the average magnitude of the reddening has also been well-studied, so generally we can account for this.

Comment: As an aside, there are situations where the spectrum we receive is featureless. In this case, determining the distance (or anything else about them, really) becomes very difficult. The most notable example of these are blazars, which we now believe to be active galactic nuclei whose ultra-relativistic jets are pointed directly at us.